# How do I use an external .class file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, classpath

I am having problems importing an external .class file into an eclipse project. I have read through most of the related questions and none of those answer have worked for me. Here is the following code for my project:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import timing.Timing;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int seed = 518406;
        long begin = 0;
        long end = 0;
        ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

        for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i=i*2){
            begin = bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            Timing.trial(i, seed);
            end = bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            System.out.println(i + ": " + (end - begin) + "ns");
        }
    }
```

}

I have imported by placing the Timing.class file in at /lib/timing/Timing.class and I have added the lib folder as a Class Folder to the build path. In the Order and Export tab of the build path window, I have moved the lib folder to the top and have it checked.

When running the code above I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Timing
        at Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Timing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In stacktrace this line looks strange

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Timing

It seems like java search `Timing` in default package not in `timing` package. Check this moment.

2 How do you run this code? From Eclipse?
If so, check Eclipse run configuration for this launch. May be you add  class folder to Build path but don't add it launch class path.

Comment: I have run the code from eclipse and from command prompt. I will check the to see if it's being added to launch class path.

Comment: Adding the timing folder to the classpath in the run configurations seemed to fix it. Thanks for the help Nestor

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're getting the `.class` file from a third-party, or you'd be including the sources.  Probably the easiest way to deal with it is to ask them to provide it wrapped in a JAR, or to pack it up yourself -- Java development tools are pretty much universally designed to handle JARs rather than raw class files.